# Global changing of H Tags

Tags: tags

Is there a way to globally change the font size for Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading 3, etc.
So, for example, if I want to change the font size for everything tagged with H2, every H2 text size on every page in the site changes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, locate the style.css file within your theme and paste the code below. I suggest using percentages in your declarations so as to keep the base size styling hopefully already in your theme.

```
h1 { font-size: 150%; }
h2 { font-size: 140%; }
h3 { font-size: 130%; }
h4 { font-size: 120%; }
h5 { font-size: 110%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the theme you are using, some themes have general settings panel labelled as **Theme Options** where you can change general & global settings like skins, typography etc. If you don't have any theme option panel  do it with css: `h1{ font-size: 24px;}`, if css doesn't work apply `!important` tag to change it forcefully `h1{ font-size: 24px !important;}, h2{ font-size: 20px !important;}` etc...

Comment: I appreciate your spelling that out for me.  I launch in a few days so I'm not going to screw with it now.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Of course.

Within your styles.css file, simply change the tag that you require as follows:

```
h1 {
    font-size: X px;
}
```

Now, if only it was that easy, right?

Here are a few things you need to **take care of**:

1) Plugins

The way plugins work is that they sometimes play with these settings too and based on which property loaded the last, that'll be your setting!

Check this out:

If `styles.css` had the declaration of

`h1 { font-size: 12px; }` but along comes a plugin that loads some other CSS and says `h1 { font-size: 14px }` guess what happens?

The `h1` now has a font size of 14px.

The only real way to ensure your styles will always over-write anything else is to either declare them via JS, which has a `post-css` execution script, meaning it executes after CSS, but this will be over-kill in terms of performance or simply make sure you manage your rules correctly.

Additionally, you can use the `!important` declaration in your styles.css file, but I find this hacky, due to:

2) User Changes

If you plan on having a dynamic theme and you allow users to change your ,`<h1>` size with `set_option`, you'll have issues unless you also declare that with `!important`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best solution to change these elements directly. For example, some themes like Automattic's own `_s` use a conditional to display the post/page title or site title.

For example, if you're on the site's index page, then the site title may be `<h1 class="site-title">Site Title</h1>` where as on a single post it might be `<p class="site-title">Site Title</p>` because on that particular page, the post title is more important.